# Remove first line while rendering data in symfony2

Tags: php, regex, symfony, twig

I am currently working on symfony2 framework. I want the html data that twig file renders in one file.

My code:

```
    $myfile = fopen("somefile.html", "w");
    $data = $this->render("somefile.html.twig");
    fwrite($myfile, $data);
```

This works fine but in addition with html data I get the following line
 "HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:       Tue, 02 Jun 2015 07:50:16 GMT"

as a staring lines I want to remove them is it possible via symfony or I have use regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use renderView() instead of render().

```
$myfile = fopen("somefile.html", "w");
$data = $this->renderView("somefile.html.twig");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ->getContent() function:

```
$myfile = fopen("somefile.html", "w");
$data = $this->render("somefile.html.twig");
fwrite($myfile, $data->getContent());
```